# Random slashes in some directory names causing issues when mounting SMB shares from Linux and macOS

Tags: linux, mount, samba

Just like the title says.  We've got a Windows Server 2003 machine serving up files through SMB - the directories in question, when browsed through Windows Explorer look fine.

But, when mounting the shares on Linux or macOS, some directory names end up with random slashes in them, which causes rsync to error out with a 'not a directory (20)' error.

How it looks in Windows:

[image: on Windows]

The same folders/directories appear like this in Linux/macOS:

[image: on Linux]

Where are these backslashes coming from?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the windows picture very exactly you can see the slashes - they are hidden under the previous letter - I have no idea how you got them there though; Windows is supposed to not allow backslashes in filenames.

It looks like a Windows prints them as a backspace followed by a backslash so it prints the slash *beneath* the previous character. The result looks like a speck, a single dot under the previous character - file**ṣ**scg...` in the first line.

Comment: Ahh good catch!  Curiously enough, in the Windows Command Prompt, the directory names show a question mark symbol where the the slash is.  Quite annoying, but luckily this isn't very important data.